# Is there a way to make a preloader for swfs in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

Is there a way to make a preloader in Javascript or JQuery so that all the elements in a webpage like the swfs and images load fully before they play and show. I have a preloader in the flash of the swfs, but some times it plays choppy. My code works properly but is it a way to preload the whole page using Javascript or JQuery before the webpage plays or shows the element with the website?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>???</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject-1.5.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(readCookie("flashPlayed") == "true"){
        Jvid()&&Bg()
    }
});

function launchFlash(){
    if(readCookie("flashPlayed") != "true"){
var homeflash = new SWFObject("???.swf", "BG", "100%", "100%", "8");
homeflash.addParam("wmode","transparent");
homeflash.write("videoBg");
var homeflash = "Bg";
setTimeout("Bg()");
setTimeout("Jvid()",5000);
setTimeout("removeFlash()",5000);
    }
}

function readCookie(cookieName){
    var searchName = cookieName + "="
    var cookies = document.cookie
    var start = cookies.indexOf(cookieName)
    if (start == -1){ // cookie not found 
        return ""
    }
    start += searchName.length //start of the cookie data
    var end = cookies.indexOf(";", start)
    if (end == -1){
        end = cookies.length
    }
    return cookies.substring(start, end)
}

function Jvid(){
    $("#videos").hide();

}
function Bg(){
    $("#test").css({"background":'url("???.jpg")',"background-position":'top center'}); 
}
function removeFlash(){
    $("#videoBg").empty();
    $("#videoBg").animate( { top:"-9999px"}, 1 );
    window.location.assign("http://???.com")
} 
</script>
<style>
#test {
    font-family: Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    background:url(???.jpg) top center repeat #000;
}

#videoBg{
position:fixed;
top:-5px;
left:0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

#videos{margin:0 auto 0;
padding:0;
height:301px;
width:205px;
position:absolute;
/*border-style:solid;
border-color:red;*/
top:134px;
left:800px;
*left:645px;
left:645px\0/;
}

</style>
</head>
<body id="test">
<div id="videos">
<script src="swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
params.wmode = "transparent";
swfobject.embedSWF("???.swf", "videos", "205", "301", "8.0.0", '', flashvars, params); 
</script>
</div>
<div id="videoBg"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
             setTimeout("launchFlash()", 7000);

    </script>


</body>
```

Comment: try updating your flash (the newer versions offer improvements but are resource hogs already, beware), test on other browsers. preloaders dont cause choppiness (what makes you say that?)

Comment: @Joseph If your page is full of JavaScript handlers and you load a new swf through ajax, the preloader of the swf sometimes cause choppiness, but it could be solved by calling part of your JS functions with `setTimeout(func,0)`, this would leave the thread to do his work better and play the preloader.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done if the flash parts would be yours. This means to make use of External Interface from AS and call JavaScript functions to tell how much is loaded, and ask when to start to play, but it is a non religious way of doing it.

Comment: Yes I have the flash of the swfs. Do you know any links to a tutorial of a External Interface AS that calls a JavaScript loader?